# 3300000/1024/1024 is 0 when printing with Awk?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have the shell script below which attempts to calculate the frequency of the CPU in GHz. The script is mostly lean under `shellcheck cpu_freq.sh`. The problem is, it does not print the cpu frequency; it prints 0:

```
$ ./cpu_freq.sh
CPU_FREQ: 0
```

Below I am using `echo`, but I have tried other things too like redirecting the file system key into the command, using a  here file and several others from stack overflow.

The script prints `0` instead of the value `3.147`. Why is the script failing to print `3.147` or so?

---

Here is a trace of the script.

```
$ bash -x cpu_freq.sh
+ GREP=grep
+ AWK=awk
...
+ CPU_FREQ=0.5
+ [[ -e /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq ]]
++ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
+ CPU_FREQ=3300000
++ echo 3300000
++ awk 'BEGIN {print $0/1024/1024; exit}'
+ CPU_FREQ=0
+ echo 'CPU_FREQ: 0'
CPU_FREQ: 0
```

---

Here is the script.

```
$ cat -n cpu_freq.sh
 1  #!/usr/bin/env bash
 2
 3  GREP=grep
 4  AWK=awk
 5
 6  THIS_SYSTEM=$(uname -s 2>&1)
 7  IS_AIX=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | "$GREP" -i -c aix)
 8  IS_DARWIN=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | "$GREP" -i -c darwin)
 9  IS_SOLARIS=$(echo -n "$THIS_SYSTEM" | "$GREP" -i -c sunos)
10
11  # Benchmarks expect frequency in GiHz.
12  CPU_FREQ=0.5
13  if [[ (-e "/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq") ]]; then
14          CPU_FREQ="$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq)"
15          CPU_FREQ="$(echo "$CPU_FREQ" | $AWK 'BEGIN {print $0/1024/1024; exit}')"
16  elif [[ (-e "/proc/cpuinfo") ]]; then
17          CPU_FREQ="$($GREP 'MHz' < /proc/cpuinfo | $AWK '{print $4; exit}')"
18          if [[ -z "$CPU_FREQ" ]]; then CPU_FREQ=512; fi
19          CPU_FREQ="$(echo $CPU_FREQ | $AWK 'BEGIN {print $0/1024}')"
20  elif [[ "$IS_DARWIN" -ne "0" ]]; then
21          CPU_FREQ="$(sysctl -a 2>&1 | $GREP "hw.cpufrequency" | $AWK '{print ($3); exit;}')"
22          CPU_FREQ="$(echo $CPU_FREQ | $AWK 'BEGIN {print $0/1024/1024/1024}')"
23  elif [[ "$IS_SOLARIS" -ne "0" ]]; then
24          CPU_FREQ="$(psrinfo -v 2>/dev/null | $GREP "MHz" | $AWK '{print $6; exit;}')"
25          CPU_FREQ="$(echo $CPU_FREQ | $AWK 'BEGIN {print $0/1024}')"
26  elif [[ "$IS_AIX" -ne "0" ]]; then
27          CPU_FREQ="$(prtconf -s 2>/dev/null | $GREP "MHz" | $AWK '{print $4; exit;}')"
28          CPU_FREQ="$(echo $CPU_FREQ | $AWK 'BEGIN {print $0/1024}')"
29  fi
30
31  echo "CPU_FREQ: $CPU_FREQ"
```

---

Here is the remaining `shellcheck` warning. I believe this one is expected.

```
In cpu_freq.sh line 15:
    CPU_FREQ="$(echo "$CPU_FREQ" | $AWK 'BEGIN {print $0/1024/1024; exit}')"
                                        ^-- SC2016: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that.
```

Answer (score 5):

`BEGIN` and `END` do not receive field values.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print $0 / 1024 / 1024 ; exit }' <<< '3300000'
0
$ awk '{ print $0 / 1024 / 1024 ; exit }' <<< '3300000'
3.14713
```

Comment: I believe that's the "file here". `CPU_FREQ="$("$AWK" 'BEGIN {print $0/1024/1024; exit}' <<< "$CPU_FREQ")"` prints 0, too.

Comment: @jww: I think you need to take a closer look at the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to use bash's file here, or can I use echo? The script above is the reduced case; the real code will require more work if I have to change the pattern to file here's.

Comment: You can use whatever you like to pass the data to awk's stdin.